# Is it possible to convert .trn (transaction log) file to human readable form

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, log

I have used below SQL statement to get the transaction information done on 2015-10-26, but the information not in human readable form.

**

```
SELECT * FROM fn_dump_dblog 
(NULL,NULL,N'DISK',1,N'D:\Inventrax369\RT\TransactionFilesForMani\FalconWMS_RT_Release_27102015.trn', 
DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT, 
DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT, 
DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT, 
DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,
DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT, 
DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT, 
DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT, DEFAULT) 
where convert(date,[Begin Time]) = convert(date,'2015-10-26')
```

**

Looking forward to receive vital suggestions.

Comment: [How to read and interpret the SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used 3rd party tools in the past when it got too difficult to track down the log file modifications, especially as the file is minimally logged to mostly record the page modifications.  Here is a tool I've used, you can search for others if you like.  It has a functional free trial.  Sometimes I install these on a VM then remove it as it does tend to embed itself sometimes.

http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx